# What is the cleanest way to group elements scattered throughout your HTML page?

Tags: html

What is the cleanest way to group elements that will be scattered throughout a page (*i.e.* they cannot all be contained within a single fieldset or other container)?

**1)** Use the `class` attribute ... (or limit using this for CSS classes?)

```
<div id="region1">
    <p class="primary">stuff</p>
    <div class="secondary">stuff</div>
</div>
stuff
<div id="region2">
    <div class="secondary">stuff</div>
    <div class="primary">stuff</div>
</div>
```

**2)** Use a "group" attribute ... (or avoid non-standard attributes on the elements?)

```
<div id="region1">
    <p group="primary">stuff</p>
    <div group="secondary">stuff</div>
</div>
stuff
<div id="region2">
    <div group="secondary">stuff</div>
    <div group="primary">stuff</div>
</div>
```

**3)** Some other way ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class. Three reasons:

1) There's no observable semantic difference between 'group' and 'class'.

2) All browsers that can handle CSS can handle class selectors--not all can handle `[group=whatever]`.

3) Typing `[group=whatever]` takes both more thought and more typing than `.whatever`.

Answer (score 2):

Class attributes, this allows you to use the class selector, in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer class statement, which is standard.

Answer (score 0):

As far as you are not using css class name as data containers, they are fine.
If you need to store meta data within your elements do it with javascript.

Comment: I don't understand.  Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Depending on what you want to establish a relationship, you should use either proper html, for semanticly related element, css for decorations, and javascript to store data which will be used to enhance user experience.